# Bigquery query to show all duplicates in a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates

Is there a way to query a table to show only those rows where a duplicate exists?
In the example below i would like to query this data and show instances where the "name" is duplicated.

```
Account#    Name    Color
1112        Jay     Blue
1113        Brian   Blue
1114        Cory    Blue
1115        Kevin   Blue
1116        Jay     Blue
1117        Billy   Blue
1118        Jay     Blue
```

In this example the following would the result:

```
Account#    Name    Color
1112        Jay     Blue
1116        Jay     Blue
1116        Jay     Blue
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT account, name, color
FROM (
  SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(account, color)) arr 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT account) > 1
), UNNEST(arr)
```

with output

```
Row account name    color    
1   1112    Jay     Blue     
2   1116    Jay     Blue     
3   1118    Jay     Blue
```

Comment: Mikhail, thanks so much for this. Can you explain what the ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(account, color)) arr  does?

Comment: `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(account, color)) arr` along with `GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT account) > 1` collects only those account/colors where name is duplicate. Than this array gets `UNNEST` back to rows and output along with respective `name`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see a few similarities between GROUP BY and OVER (PARTITION BY) . Am i able to use COUNT (DISTINCT) only in conjunction with GROUP BY?

Comment: technically - you can use `COUNT (DISTINCT)` with `OVER (PARTITION BY)` but only if OVER does not have ORDER BY clause in it. btw, consider voting up the answer if it was helpful :o)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.* except (cnt)
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name, color) as cnt
      from test123 t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

You only mention `name` in terms of duplicates, but I am thinking that color is also important.  If you really only care about `name`, remove `color` from the subquery.

Comment: this somewhat worked, although i had to remove the last 't' after the )

Comment: @CarloB. . . . I rather confused on why you think this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why... but when copy pasted as you have it, and replace all occurrences of 't' with project.dataset.table i get the error "Unexpected keyword EXCEPT" which i can only seem to clear by having SELECT * EXCEPT (cnt)...then when i do that, i have to remove the last 't'

Comment: @CarloB. . . . Just replace the first `t` with your table name and follow that with a `t`.

Comment: the only way i can get this to work is: select test123.* except (cnt)
from (select test123.*, count(*) over (partition by name, color) as cnt
      from project.dataset.test123
     ) test123
where cnt > 1;

Comment: @CarloB. . . . Just make `t` the alias for your table name and it all works.  If you had mentioned the name in your question, then I would have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * 
    from t t1, t t2
    where t1.name = t2.name
    and  t1.color = t2.color
    and t1.account# <> t2.account#;
```